# How do I file CA state taxes without a SSN or ITIN?

Tags: usa, taxes, uk-citizens, california

Background: UK citizen, spent a summer as a J1 intern in California. Didn't get a SSN.

So I sent my US federal tax return and ITIN application to the US embassy London. Fairly sure that was the correct thing to do. Now I realize I need to file CA taxes as well (at least, I think I do, as I'm a "part-year resident"?) Do I send a CA tax return to the US embassy London or to Sacramento? Do I need to do another ITIN application?

Comment: Were you a resident of the state of California in the past year?  Did you receive any income in the state?  What was your status when you were there?

Comment: As I said in the question, I spent a summer (3 months) as a J1 intern, earning about $12k.

Comment: Did you get any income reporting forms such as W-2 or 1099?

Comment: You may need to consult an accountant regarding whether you need to file or not.  The [Do I need to file section for 540NR](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2013/13_540nrbk.pdf) may indicate that you don't have enough income to require filing.

Comment: Yep, I got a W2

Comment: Is there anything in Box a?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the thing according to [IRS Publication 15 Section 4](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf) and [W-2 Instructions](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw2w3.pdf) the employer when filling out the W-2 form which you have received must provide an SSN or ITIN in [Box a on the form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw2.pdf), which means that if you need to file as Non-Resident or Part Year resident in California you should use the same ID that was provided to you on the W-2.

If the employer didn't provide this information on the form it is likely to be considered a violation with fines or other consequences.